# Fragment still visible after replace

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have looked all over on here and pretty much tried everything. I have my main activity which contains my Toolbar and TabLayout, this loads a fragment known as ActiveThreadFragment. I then replace ActiveThreadFragment with another called PostFragment. Here is the issue that's happening:
[PostFragment Overlapping ActiveThreadFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYhE9.png)

Here's my code for replacing ActiveThreadFragment with PostFragment

```
private void showItemSelectedAtPosition(int position) {
    Threads selectedThread = mData.getItem(position);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_thread,
            PostFragment.newInstance(selectedThread.getThreadItem()));
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Here is the layout for ActiveThreadFragment where the FrameLayout 'content_thread' is to replace with it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_thread"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/threadRecyclerView"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.7"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong and can't figure out? Am I just being really silly? I can provide more code or anything else if needed.

Comment: Are you using nesting of Fragments? Because you are getting the fragmnetManager as  getChildFragmentManager();

Comment: try removing recyclerview for once and check the flow?

Comment: Removing the recyclerView helps, I'll do that for now. And when the user presses back I can just reload the previous fragment manually, right? @sector11

Comment: you don't need to do that manually, it is take by fragment transaction manager if you add fragment to backstack Better be using fragment and manager from support package :D

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you @sector11 :D